# Shorthand for defining class accessors in module

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I find myself writing code like the following a lot:

```
module SomeModule
  module ClassMethods
    def some_attribute
      @some_attribute
    end
    def some_attribute=(val)
      @some_attribute = val
    end
  end
  def self.included(other)
    other.extend ClassMethods
  end      
end

class MyClass
  include SomeModule
  self.some_attribute = "a value"
end
```

Is there a shorthand for the two class methods defined above? Something like `attr_accessor` but for class methods.

[EDIT]

Based on sawa's answer the `self.included` method can be changed to:

```
def self.included(other)
  other.singleton_class.class_eval{attr_accessor :some_attribute}
end
```

Comment: In future, consider waiting awhile before selecting an answer.  A rush to judgement discourages other answers and, imo, is disrespectful to those still working on answers mere minutes after the question was asked. (That did not apply to me.)

Comment: Well I can't really see what else another answerer could add here. If someone submits an answer that is correct they will still get upvotes, and I have the option to unaccept the accepted answer if necessary. I don't really think it is necessary to wait if the question has been answered

Comment: I think @CarySwoveland is referring to the fact that the solution you decided to take may not be the cleanest in terms of design. What if you need more accessors ? You would end up with a very ugly block in your class_eval method. Another thing to notice is that this code is a bit harder to read than the one I suggested, because of that chained method calls.

Comment: My point is simple: there are arguments for waiting awhile before selecting an answer, and no arguments for not doing so (other than the one about candy in one's pocket).

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think you're right on this one. We can have a bunch of correct answers, but even so it is nice to wait and decide the best approach rather than "It works. It is correct.". Programmers should always pay attention to best practices, specially when dealing with metaprogramming =P

Comment: You have no argument from me on that, Sliced.  I prefer `class << self` because I read it as 'change `self` to the singleton class', which is precisely what's happening, but there's no reason we need agree on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyClass
  singleton_class.class_eval{attr_accessor :some_attribute}
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
module SomeModule
  def self.included(other)
    class << other 
      attr_accessor :some_attribute
    end
  end      
end

class MyClass
  include SomeModule
  self.some_attribute = "a value"
end
```

**Note:** Don't forget the `self` before calling `some_attribute=`. You need the explicit receiver on writter methods or Ruby will think you're trying to assign a variable somewhere =P

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done like this:

```
module SomeModule
  attr_accessor :some_attribute
end

class MyClass
  extend SomeModule
  @some_attribute = "life is grand"
end

MyClass.some_attribute #=> "life is grand"
```

But why not just the usual way?

```
class MyClass
  class << self
    attr_accessor :some_attribute
  end
end

MyClass.some_attribute = "life is grand"
MyClass.some_attribute #=> "life is grand"
```

Comment: Good point, in my case the module has other functionality which requires it to be included. (I should probably have mentioned that in the question)